# Unity5 build won't run on android 2.3.3

Tags: android, unity

I made a game using one of the Unity tutorials on their site and now would like to run on my phone (LG P500). But when I try to run it on the device, it says:

> Failure to initialize: Your hardware does not support this application, sorry!

What can I do in this case?

Comment: did you check your project setting? some of the features only works in specific phones.

Comment: I'm not sure what I should look for?

Comment: check the player settings. make sure everything is marked as default and also check Minimum API level is set to 2.3.3

Comment: Is there any additional information in the logcat output?

Comment: what tutorial did you follow? if you provide a linkbwe might be able to determine if it uses anything unsupported by your version

Answer (score 1):

Unity is probably set to build for Android 4.0.3 (or something higher than 2.3.3).

You can change this in the Player Settings.

Comment: "Minimum API Level" - ? It's set to 2.3.1 so probably not this.